# Is there any alternative for CONCAT() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, combinations, concatenation

I want to add a constant string to all result of one column. Here is my table:

```
// mytable

 id | name
----|--------
 1  | jack
 2  | peter
 3  | ali
```

I want this output:

```
select name from mytable order by id;

Your name: jack
Your name: peter
Your name: ali
```

As you see, I have combined all results of `name` column with this string: `Your name:`. I can do that like this:

```
... CONCAT('Your name: ', name) ...
```

Now I want to know, is there any approach else? (something like combining by `+` in MySQL)

Comment: What is wrong with using `concat` function since `+` is an arithmetic operator in mysql ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I think using a function like `concat()`  is not fast *(not optimized)*

Comment: No thats a wrong assumption, `concat()` function is just to concat strings and it has nothing to do with query speed.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty alright then, Thanks :)

Comment: For me I am using a framework that takes apart CONCAT() by `explode(',',$string)` which massively doesn't help when used in an OrderBy (Codeigniter 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONCAT` is the default way to do string concatenation. `+` is arithemtic operator and when you try:

```
SELECT 'a' + 'b'  -- you will get 0, because of implicit cast to number
```

There is also `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(SPACE(1), 'Your name:','Bob') AS result
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/27573/0)**</kbd>

Comment: question is not really answered here, there's a bug on Android Studio (or I am missing something) so the CONCAT and CONCAT_WS keywords are not recognised and impossible to use. So question remains. Any alternatives?

Comment: @AndrewBloom Are you connecting from AndroidStudio to MySQL instance or maybe SQLite(if yes, then concatenate operator is `SELECT 'a' || 'b'`)

Comment: @Lucasz Szozda that comment was actually so long ago i'm not even remember what i wanted to achieve. Working on a completely different project since 1 year now.